# jTable raise formSubmitting with custom jQueryUI Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I am not being able to raise the [formSubmitting](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#event-formSubmitting) event when I am submitting a custom jQueryUI modal using jTable. Following is the jqeuryui modal code:

```
$("#editDialog").dialog({
    height: 600,
    width: 500,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 250
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 250
    },
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Save: function () {
            $(this).find("form").submit();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        //allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not. Ended up showing the custom modal on own bound click event.